# navbar and column layout doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

So my site is the [following](http://www.shopious.com/), when I was opening this in chrome it worked just fine.. the logo on top right is left aligned and at the bottom where it has testimonials it has a 3 column layout. However, when I open this on firefox, the logo is not left aligned (centered) and the three column is now a one line.

My css for the logo looks like this:

```
.navbar-shopious-color .navbar-inner .nav-title-logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working for firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the logo..

```
.navbar-shopious-color .navbar-inner .nav-title-logo {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And changing the `-moz-column-fill` to `balance` should fix the testimonials

```
.testimony-container {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: balance;
}
```